# Generate series like from 0001 to something in postgres

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I want to generate numbers from the a min to a max number. I have an inbuilt function in postgres generate_series(int,int) that can easily do that. My problem is that am working with a text field because i would like to capture values like 0001. If there is no other inbuilt function that can keep this format, i would then want to extract the preceeding zeroes then append them to the function generate_series(int, int). Any solution regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to format the numbers returned by `generate_series()`

```
select to_char(n, 'FM0000')
from generate_series(1,1000) as x(n);
```

The `FM` removes leading white space from the output.

Online example: https://rextester.com/IWET48678

Comment: Thanks From the above answers now i have the solution.

Answer (score -1):

First create a sequence to get the id as integer:

```
create sequence test;
```

Then create a sql function to return the value as varchar:

```
create or replace function ser() returns varchar as
$$
select right('000' || nextval('test')::varchar,4) as id;
$$
language sql;
```

To get the incremented value in statements you can call the function `ser()` which will return always the new value of the sequence as a varchar:

'0001'
'0002'
'0003'
etc

Remember that when you call the function the value will always increment as it will work like a primary key.